# Is it possible to dynamically create divs using ONLY html, css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add (and display) divs when a user presses a button, I'm also using css grids. I've had a look here and all the solutions advise using angular js or node js.

I've recently (last week) learnt html, css and javascript and I'm pressed for time hence I'm asking if is it possible to create these divs without angular js or node js?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: yeah its just <div></div>

Comment: People were creating dynamic HTML long, long before Angular was even dreamed of. And Node really has nothing at all to do with it.

Comment: @L_Church I know that method I, that's hard coding it. I needed the user to be able to add columns to a grid I created at the press of a button. I got the answer.

Comment: html is not code it's markup

Comment: @L_Church thanks for that. A lot of the tutorials I've been watching refer to it as code.

Comment: we've all been in your shoes. HyperText **Markup** Language :) good luck

Comment: and yet when you look up a list of all programming languages, it's there...

Answer (score 4):

You can create HTML elements by using [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

It's acutally pretty simple:

```js
function add() {
  // Create element; can be whatever you want, e. g. div, h1, p, img...
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  
  // Set some attributes
  div.style.width = '200px';
  div.style.height = '200px';
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  
  // Append the div to the body
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">Add div</button>
```

Comment: @kuhle Glad to help! Please consider marking my answer as the one that helped you out.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do it.

1. The obvious one is the mysteriously-named [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), usually combined with [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) and/or [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):

   ```
   parent.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
   ```
2. You can replace the contents of a parent element by assigning a string containing HTML to its [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

   ```
   parent.innerHTML = "<div></div>";
   ```
3. #2 *replaces* the parent's content. To *add to* it, you can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), again with a string containing HTML:

   ```
   parent.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div></div>");
   ```

Lots to discover in [MDN's DOM section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: Crowder, thank you so much. I'm learning a lot from that DOM section.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `document.createElement`

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>    
            function CreateDiv(){
                var myDiv = document.createElement("DIV"); // Create a <div> node
                var myTextNode = document.createTextNode("Hello World"); // Create a text node
                myDiv.appendChild(myTextNode); // Append the text 

                //document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node); // Append 
                document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
            }

        </script>
        <input type="button" onclick="CreateDiv();" value="Create div">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native createElement() method.

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");       // Create a text node
btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(btn);                    // Append <button> to <body>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Comment: I appreciate the reference to the link. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <button class="btn"
    onclick="document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Hello'">
    Click On Me</button>
    <p id="text"></p>
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Check this one.