# How to populate a HTML page with Firebase data?

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to populate a page with firebase data.
This is my firebase data structure...[image: firebase data structure]

What I want is to create number of divs according to the number of posts in firebase. And in the divs with title and subtitle in h2 tag and p tag.

I am new to firebase soo any help would be appreciated...
and also i want to limit the number of divs to 4 starting from the latest post.

this is my java script

```
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var postsRef = firebase.database().ref("posts").orderByKey();
postsRef.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    var key = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    var name_val = childSnapshot.val().title;
    var id_val = childSnapshot.val().subtitle;

     console.log(name_val);
     var post = document.getElementById('#tst-post');

    var divh2 = document.createElement('h2');
    divh2.innerText - childData.val().title + "---" + JSON.stringify(childData.val());
    $(post).append(divh2);
  });
});
```

i dont know what i am doing in this code, I just watched some tutorials. Please help me.

Comment: Hello. See my answer. If I may, asking a question on Stack Overflow with saying "I don't know what I am doing in this code" is probably not the best way to receive some answers (and it will probably result in having your question closed). Please see the help on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not very far from a result.

By searching on the internet (https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=how+to+dynamically+create+div+in+javascript) you can easily find a lot of examples on how to create DIVs dynamically. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50950179/3371862

Then, in the Firebase Realtime Database documentation you find how to [filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data) and in particular how to "Sets the maximum number of items to return from the end of the ordered list of results" with `limitToLast()`.

So if you put all of that together as follows, it should do the trick:

```
<script>
  var postsRef = firebase
    .database()
    .ref('posts')
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(4);
  postsRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      var name_val = childSnapshot.val().title;
      var id_val = childSnapshot.val().subtitle;

      createDiv(name_val, id_val);
    });
  });

  function createDiv(title, subtitle) {
    var myDiv = document.createElement('DIV'); // Create a <div> node
    var myTitle = document.createTextNode(title); // Create a text node
    myDiv.appendChild(myTitle); // Append the text
    var mySubtitle = document.createTextNode(subtitle); // Create a text node
    myDiv.appendChild(mySubtitle); // Append the text

    myDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
    myDiv.style.border = 'solid';
    myDiv.style.margin = '10px';

    document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
  }
</script>
```